# Invalid spec when I run pod.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I run my Pod I get the Pod (cas-de) is invalid spec : forbidden pod updates may not change fields other than the  `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)

However, I searched on the kubernetes website and I didn't find anything wrong: 
(I really don't understand where is my mistake)

Does it better to set `volumeMounts` in a Pod or in Deployment?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: cas-de
  namespace: ds-svc
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ds-mg-cas
    image: "docker-all.xxx.net/library/ds-mg-cas:latest"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8443
    - containerPort: 6402
    env:
    - name: JAVA_APP_CONFIGS
      value: "/apps/ds-cas/configs"
    - name: JAVA_EXTRA_PARAMS
      value: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./config/jaas.config -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6402"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: ds-cas-config
      mountPath: "/apps/ds-cas/context"
  volumes:
    - name: ds-cas-config
      hostPath:
        path: "/apps/ds-cas/context"
```

Comment: Are you creating a new pod or updating one?
Also, is the pod in question already part of a deployment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

YAML template is valid. Some of the fields might have been changed that are forbidden and then `kubectl apply ....` is executed.

Looks like more like a development. Solution is to delete the existing pod using `kubectl delete pod cas-de` command and then execute `kubectl apply -f file.yaml` or `kubectl create -f file.yaml`.

Comment: Just faced this error, and come to know that the if you have used  kubectl create , and pod is running and on top of it if you are running kubectl apply it will always give such errors, because the api which get generated internally it doesn't have the filed which you have added. so just use, kubectl create if you have already used kubectl create, or delete the deployment and use create or apply

Answer (score 6):

There are several fields on objects that you simply aren't allowed to change after the object has initially been created.  As a specific example, [the reference documentation for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core) notes that `volumeMounts` "cannot be updated".  If you hit one of these cases, you need to delete and recreate the object (possibly creating the new one first with a different name).

> Does it better to set `volumeMounts` in a Pod or in Deployment?

Never use bare Pods; always prefer using one of the Controllers that manages Pods, most often a Deployment.

Changing to a Deployment will actually solve this problem because updating a Deployment's pod spec will go through the sequence of creating a new Pod, waiting for it to become available, and then deleting the old one for you.  It never tries to update a Pod in place.